Customize @mui TextField type=number arrows
I'm using the https://mui.com/material-ui/ library and importing the TextField component.
What I need is to shape it like this one:
enter image description here
The issue is I am not able to:

always show the up/down arrows (even when there is no hover)

show them with my custom style (on all browsers)


I'm currently creating a custom component CustomTextField using the @mui/material styled function, but I cannot change anything even accessing:
"& .MuiInputBase-root"

Basically I would like to replicate this style: https://mui.com/base-ui/react-number-input/
Thank you!

Use
<TextField
            InputProps={
                {
                    endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment position="end">
                            <Stack direction={"column"}>
                                <ArrowDropUp sx={{border:"1px solid #c0c0c0",borderTopLeftRadius:3,borderTopRightRadius:3,}}/>
                                <ArrowDropDown sx={{border:"1px solid #c0c0c0",borderBottomLeftRadius:3,borderBottomRightRadius:3,}}/>
                            </Stack>
                        </InputAdornment>
                    )
                }
            }
        />

